# Can't choose interpolation attributes of my shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, interpolation

I am attempting to interpolate data of a point shapefile. In the attribute table all attributes are shown correctly. When I am trying to interpolate them with Raster >> Interpolation no attributes to choose are shown. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello I am having exactly the same problem here
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrXjx.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrXjx.jpg)

Comment: Good afternoon, i have the same problem. I have an input linear shapefile data. But my integer field is not recognized by interpolation plugin. i attach an usefull screenshot. In advance, thank you to throw light for me. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk7nZ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk7nZ.jpg)

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. If you have the same question, wait for someone to answer this one. If you have a different but related question, post it as its own question and include a link to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which fields you are talking about, but it seems you are attempting to interpolate based on a field of joined table which is not in the original shapefile. To use interpolation on a shapefile there are many points you have to check:

1. The fields should be embedded in the attribute table
2. Field names should not exceed 10 characters in shapefile
3. Spaces are not valid in field names
4. Fields type should be of numerical type. If the fields are of text type you cannot select anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked your points. The fields are embedded and I shortened the field names. Also I deleted spaces in the field names. Fields type is qlonglong, typename is Integer64. When using the table I connectet to my shapefile i am able to choose attributes in the interpolationtool but the content is not shown.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't understand. You cannot see the contents in attribute table or in the interpolation tool, where exactly?

Comment: In the interpolation tool, I'll upload a screenshot

Comment: If M is the desired field, then it is correct. You need to specify the cell size for x and y. Then you need to specify the output file name with an extension like tif or img.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are still searching for an answer but I had the same issue. By changing attribute as mentioned [here](https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Change_Attribute_Type)  and forcing the qlonglong / Integer64 to double/double and refactoring the data, I was able to select the changed fields as interpolation attribute.

Hope it will work for you too.